# Rearranging a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

Hi I am trying to rearrange a differential equation like

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=-\pi y(y-2r) \frac{dy}{dt}$$

I did

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{\frac{dV}{dt}}{-\pi y(y-2r) }$$

but apparently I am wrong, I can't see why but maybe it's that the equation needs to be in its simplest form

Any help appreciated

:)

Comment: There are many not-wrong and simultaneously not-useful ways to rearrange that equation.